# print a table of decremented numbers

Tags: c++

I want to write a code that print a table like this:

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

I wrote a code to print a table as said above, but it just print 5's.
I know that I have to use a condition to print such a table. What's the condition to print it ?

```
int main () {
int  number = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (condition)
            ...
        else
            cout << number << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solving it here would spoil the exercise, wouldn't it?  Start by looking how you would do it by hand and see what loops you need.  How would you only print the middle line?

Comment: Hint: You're printing something that's _almost_ the distance to the center.

Comment: stefaanv , I didn't said that I need someone to solve it completely for me.
I just need a  Hint or ... that How the condition would be.

Comment: Hint: the numbers you are printing is the distance to the center resulting from the [uniform norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) + 1

Comment: Hint2: I dont see what condition could make your program work. Instead I would rather look for a formula to calculate each number (see e.g. my last hint)

Comment: okey . so you mean  uniform norm ?

Comment: I just noticed that `uniform norm` denotes the norm in the case of a function space. For a finite dimensional vector space (ie. the 2d plane in your case) it is called Chebyshev norm. Sorry, I am not too familiar with the english terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, what you want to print is the [Chebyshev distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) to the center +1. I dont know what condition can make your code work, but instead I would use a simple formula to calculate each value:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<9;j++){
            cout << std::max(abs(i-4),abs(j-4)) +1 << " " ;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry if I spoiled your exercise of writing the code on your own, but I wanted to save you from thinking it needs more than a single line to get it done....

Comment: thank you dear. actually I thought that i can do it with give some conditions to it. but i didn't care about function's like max and abs.
anyway, thank you. So It's so simple to do with these functions.

Answer (score -3):

```
    /*To make boxes and inside box and so on
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<iostream.h>
    void main()
    {
    int a[100][100],n,i,j,k=0,l;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter the outside  No. n \n";
    //like for your answer it is 5;
    //i and j are loop element for 2D array
    //k is used for making n boxes
    cin>>n;
    l=n;
    n=2*n-1;
    while(k<n)
    {
        if(k%2==0)
        {
        for(i=k;i<n-k;i++)
        {
            a[0+k][i]=l;
            a[i][0+k]=l;
            a[n-1-k][i]=l;
            a[i][n-1-k]=l;
        }
        k++;l--;
        }
        else
        {
        for(i=k;i<n-k;i++)
        {
            a[0+k][i]=l;
            a[i][0+k]=l;
            a[n-1-k][i]=l;
            a[i][n-1-k]=l;
        }
        k++;l--;
        }
    }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                cout << a[i][j];
                if(a[i][j]>9)
                cout<<" ";
                else
                cout<<"  ";
            }
        cout<<endl;
        }

    getch();
    }
```

Comment: explain your code in answer always.. this increases readability of your contribution.. thank you

Comment: Thank you. but i think it's so complex.
Can you give me the name of this program ?

Comment: `conio.h` is quite non-standard.

Comment: this solution might work, but it is far too complicated. The problem can be solved in one line (inside two for loops)

Comment: This is simple to understand i'd just making first a box then an inner box and so on until value of k reaches to n the value u wanted outside.For making this to hundred you have to write the following code:-

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30480584/edit) your question. Don't put explanations into comments. And your last edit simply commented out all code. I'm really having a hard time understanding what it takes, to completely ignore the live preview provided in the edit interface.